Is changing syntax of require("node:fs") to require("fs") an acceptable workaround inside OpenAI package
I am working on an already-created project and trying to add OpenAI to it. I had been initially informed that Node 16 version is to be used but found out later through other devs that everyone is on 14.17.3 and same is used all over the project.
The OpenAI package has require("node:fs") syntax in it from where the error "module not found" originates.
Since Node 14 can use fs without node: I wanted to know if this is an acceptable workaround to my problem or this is dangerous (feels dangerous).
I tried to go through the older versions of OpenAI package but the earliest 4.0.0 still mentions Node 16 as requirement and the versions older than that have a warning attached to them. So my other question would be how to know exactly which version of Node will be compatible with which version of OpenAI package. Asking this because when I was using Node 16 and installed OpenAI the version was latest and in there the requirement mentioned is 18 so it still works with 16. So would that be the case when finding 14 compatible version as well?

Not answering your question, but this image might interest you https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases#release-schedule

There's no guarantee - it might be using any of the other syntax that's valid in 16+ but not 14, see e.g. https://node.green/. As the comment above shows Node 14 (and 16 for that matter) is no longer supported, so even if you can coax one package into working by editing the code directly (bad idea) you'll likely just be playing whack-a-mole with other errors.

Thanks for the response @jonsharpe. It makes sense not to do it.

You can check the compatible version of Node using the following command npm view <package> engines:
$ npm view react@17.0.1 engines
{ node: '>=0.10.0' }


Ah thanks for this. Even in this the node version after doing npm view openai@4.47.1 the node version is shown as @types/node: ^18.11.18. But I had installed it with node 16 on my local system and it was working as well.
